# Json result is nothing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json

I'm use this code for access my server (MVC) and this work fine. In the result "data" ( {"Id":30,"Description":"Samples Photos","Name":"First Galery"}) I try get the property data.Name and this just return nothing, what is the problem in this code?

JavaScript

```
 $(function () {
        $('#UserGaleries_').change(function () {
            try {

                if ($(this).val() == -1) {

                    $('#NameGaleriesEdit').val('');
                    $('#DescriptionGaleriesEdit').val('');

                }
                else {
                    $.post('/UserGaleries/ChangeCategorie',
                        { selectedID: $(this).val() },
                        function (data) {
                            alert(data.Name); //Nothing
                            $('#NameGaleriesEdit').val(data.name);
                            $('#DescriptionGaleriesEdit').val('asdf');

                        });
                }
            } catch (e) {
                alert(e);
            }

        });
    });
```

MVC

```
[Serializable]
public class ResponsetModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public JsonResult ChangeCategorie(int selectedID)
{
    DbLayer.UserGaleriesManager uc = new DbLayer.UserGaleriesManager();
    DbLayer.Models.UsersGalery cat = uc.GetGaleriesById(selectedID);

    ResponsetModel retValue = new ResponsetModel()
    { Id = cat.Id, Name = cat.Title, Description = cat.Description };

    JsonResult oView = Json(retValue, "text/plain", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    return oView;
}
```

Comment: Your ChangeCategories action method needs the HttpPost attribute

Comment: @Jon. That is incorrect.

Comment: Don't know the mysteries of JavaScript, but have you tried calling data().name instead?

Comment: It looks like case sensitive issue: `data.name` or `data.Name` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `post()` method without specifying expected content type, the `data` will be simply a string containing JSON (as opposed to JavaScript object). Do `alert(data)` to verify that.

Rewrite that post as

```
$.ajax({
    url:'/UserGaleries/ChangeCategorie',
    data:{ selectedID: $(this).val() },
    method:"POST",
    dataType:"json",
    success:function (data) {
        alert(data.Name);
    }
});
```

Alternatively you can use `$.getJSON()`, but I am not sure if you can make it execute POST request.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try to set the dataType in the $.post( ) to "json". Check the example in the [documentation].[1](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

It is also `data.Name` not `data.name`.

Something like this:

```
$.post('/UserGaleries/ChangeCategorie',
              { selectedID: $(this).val() },
              function (data) {
                            alert(data.Name);
                            $('#NameGaleriesEdit').val(data.Name);
                            $('#DescriptionGaleriesEdit').val('asdf');

              }, "json");
```

Important recommendation: Use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to check what it is the exact response from your application server.

Answer (score 1):

You can also parse the JSON data after it's returned by using `JSON.parse(result)`.

Answer (score -1):

Try using a different way of accessing the data.  Use data["Name"]

Comment: I do not think this will make any difference.... data["Name"] and data.Name should be the same if the dataType is json.